# SceneKit hair bones dynamic movement limitation, hair animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, scenekit

I have a .dae model of head with long hair, divided by strands. Every strand has its own tree of bones. I've spent a lot of time to find some 
solution - it construct on example with rope from GitHub

https://github.com/orff/sceneKitRope

so I've setup every tree of bones with branch node

```
let strand_branch = SCNNode(geometry: SCNCylinder(radius: 0.007, height: CGFloat(_branchHeight)))
strand_branch.name = "branch_\(branch.rawValue)"
strand_branch.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = SKColor.clear
strand_branch.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.static()
strand_branch.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
strand_branch.position = first_bone_position
currentScene!.rootNode.addChildNode(strand_branch)
```

next I've setup every bone like this

```
bone.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamic()
bone.physicsBody?.friction = 0.5
bone.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
bone.physicsBody?.mass = mass
bone.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false
bone.physicsBody?.damping = 0.5
bone.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.5
```

and after that I've add **SCNPhysicsBallSocketJoint** to the branch and first bone, and to the every pair of bones.

so now physics simulations of hair works, but it is problem with bones position limitation. I want to limit every strand of hair to prevent it from cover the face. 
My goal is light smooth hair animation like in Apple memodji.

Please help! Thanks!